# Possessivpronomen. Manchmal nur eine Geschmackssache?

Tags: usage, personal-pronoun

Beispiel Sätze sind wie folgendes;

> Du hast alles **in der Hand**

vs

> Du hast alles **in deiner Hand**

---

> Ich bewahre mir diese Bilder **im Kopf**

vs

> Ich bewahre mir diese Bilder **in meinem Kopf**

---

> Was hast du **auf dem Herzen**?

vs

> Was hast du **auf deinem Herzen**?

Macht die Verwendung von Possessivpronomen in dem obigen Fall (Kopf, Herz, Hand sind Körperteile) einen Unterschied? Falls ja, was ist dieser Unterschied, falls nein, kann man auch diese alternative (freiwillige) Benutzung von Personalpronommen auch außer den Körperteilen verwenden?

Comment: Die Aussagen ohne Possessivpronomen klingen einfach idiomatischer. Das Possessivpronomen klingt einfach nur ungewohnt in diesen Situationen.

Comment: Im Englischen wird das Posssesivpronomen bei Körperteilen verwendet, im Deutschen ergibt sich aus dem Kontext, ob es der eigene Kopf / Bauch / Arm oder der einesanderen ist. Daher ist es eher unüblich (aber nicht falsch), das Posessivpronomen hier zu benutzen.

Comment: Possesivpronomen wirken auch demonstrativ: *Du hast es in deiner Hand.* zeigt nochmals demonstrativ auf die fremde Hand.

Comment: @Robert: Würde sich das im Englischen nicht auch aus dem Kontext ergeben?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Konstruktionen sind alle fast gleichbedeutend und zum Teil fast zwingend gleich: man kann schließlich kaum etwas auf einer *anderen* Hand haben als der eigenen.

Trotzdem ist die Formulierung bedeutungstragend. Zwei Varianten derselben Aussage können dennoch verschiedene idiomatische Bedeutungen erhalten. Zum Beispiel kann eine im übertragenen Sinn und eine im direkten Sinn. An Deinen Beispielen kann man das hervorragend beobachten:

> Du hast es in der Hand = "It's up to you" (übertragen)
>
> Du hast es in Deiner Hand = "You're holding it in your hand" (direkt)
>
> Ich habe es im Kopf = "It's going through my mind" *or* "I've got it down by heart"
>
> Ich habe es in meinem Kopf = more likely "It's on my mind"

Im allgemeinen neigen die kürzeren Varianten eher dazu, eine übertragene Bedeutung anzunehmen.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort, danke schön. Außer den Körperteilen kann man auch diese kürzeren Varianten benutzen? Ich meine z.b bedeutet **Was hast du in der Tasche?** immer **Was hast du in deiner Tasche?**

Comment: @AdInfinitum Edited - ja, diese Ausdrücke funktionieren genauso.

Comment: Sehr gut es zu wissen. Danke nochmal.