# Possessivadjektive und Körperteile

Tags: article, reflexive, possessive

Ich habe mehrere Male bemerkt, dass im Kontext der Körperteile in der deutschen Sprache oft kein Possessivadjektiv benutzt wird. Stattdessen gibt es einen Artikel. Zum Beispiel:

> Sie hat sich das Knie beim Marathonlauf verletzt.

Im Gegensatz dazu würde man auf Englisch sagen:

> She injured her knee at the marathon.

Es scheint mir daher, dass hier das deutsche Reflexivpronomen die Funktion der englischen Possessivadjektiv übernimmt. Gerade bin ich einem ähnlichen Beispiel begegnet, das einem englischen Muttersprachler noch mehr auffällt:

> Dann pochet mir das Herz.

Meine Frage ist also: Verwendet man im Kontext der Körperteilen immer ein Reflexivpronomen anstelle eines Possessivadjektivs? Und wenn nicht, in welchen Kontexten könnte ich (zum Beispiel) bloß »die Hand« sagen und damit auf »meine Hand« verweisen? In welchen Kontexten wird ein Reflexivpronomen notwendig?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/37069/22136

Answer (score 7):

Zuerst mal: Im Deutschen gibt es keine Possessivadjektive. Diese Wortart ist mir nur aus slawischen Sprachen (z.B. Kroatisch) bekannt. Die Wörter *[mein](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein), [dein](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dein), [unser](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/unser)* usw. sind Possessiv*pronomen*. (In manchen Lehrbüchern findet man auch die Bezeichnung Possessivartikel, jedoch ist diese Bezeichnung weniger verbreitet.)

Wenn in einem Satz durch ein Reflexivpronomen ohnehin klar gekennzeichnet ist, wessen Körperteil gemeint ist, muss dieser Bezug nicht mehr zusätzlich durch Possessivpronomen angezeigt werden. Ein ganz gewöhnlicher Artikel reicht hier:

> Sie verletzt **sich** *das* Knie.
>   **Mir** pocht *das* Herz.

Auch Kleidungsstücke kann man so verwenden, ebenso alles andere das man besitzt:

> Ich habe **mir** *die* Hose zerrissen.
>   Sie hat **mir** *das* Auto zerkratzt.

Das funktioniert auch mit Personalpronomen, die sich nicht auf das Subjekt beziehen:

> Ich schlage **dir** gleich *die* Zähne ein.
>   Das kann **dich** *den* Job kosten.

Im Englischen ist das nicht möglich, weil solche Sätze weder mit einem Reflexivpronomen noch mit einen Personalpronomen gebildet werden:

> *Falsch:*
>   <del>My/the heart ponds **me**.</del>
>   <del>I'll hit **you** your/the teeth.</del>

Die Verwendung eines Possessivpronomens ist aber trotzdem erlaubt und stilistisch gleichwertig:

> Sie verletzt **sich** *ihr* Knie.
>   **Mir** pocht *mein* Herz.
>   Ich habe **mir** *meine* Hose zerrissen.
>   Sie hat **mir** *mein* Auto zerkratzt.
>   Ich schlage **dir** gleich *deine* Zähne ein.
>   Das kann **dich** *deinen* Job kosten.

Comment: wie immer: fantastische Antwort. Vielleicht ein Satz zur Vervollständigung: Meiner Meinung nach ist im deutschen die Verwendung des einfachen Artikels sogar häufiger und das Possesivpronomen wird eher zur besonderen Betonung oder Vermeidung von Zweideutigkeit verwendet: `Sie hat mit das Auto zerkratzt` würde beispielsweise auch funktionieren, wenn ich mit einem fremden Auto unterwegs bin...

Comment: @TorstenLink: Auch wenn du mit einem fremden Auto unterwegs bist (du bist nicht der Eigentümer), so ist das in diesem. Moment aber doch dein Auto (du bist der Besitzer). Juristisch wird streng zwischen Eigentum, Besitz und Innehaltung unterschieden (zumindest in Österreich): Eigentum: Ich habe das Recht das Ding weiterzugeben und ich darf es auch zerstören. Besitz: Ich habe das Recht, das Ding zu verwenden (typisch: Miete). Innehaltung: Ich habe keine Rechte, sondern nur die Pflicht darauf aufzupassen solange es in meinem Gewahrsam ist (z.B. Mantel in bewachter Garderobe)

Comment: Juristisch hast Du vollkommen recht... Ich meinte auch eher die Unterscheidung zwischen meinem eigenen Auto (also mein Eigentum) und dem Auto, das ich gerade fahre (Besitz), wenn ich jemandem erzähle, dass ein Auto zerkratzt wurde. Aber das ist eigentlich Haarspalterei...